# Suspicious voting + answering duo

Tags: discussion, sock-puppets

There is some pretty bizarre voting going on over on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844131/comparing-exception-objects-in-python/15844248). Normally, I'd just leave it alone, but there are a few things that are really weird about this case:

1. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15844247/1204143) [10k only] is trolling, obviously, but since the guy clearly doesn't have enough rep to cast downvotes, he is using an alternate account to do it.
2. [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250416/bobby-jones) commented on my post, chastising me for commenting. OK, but if you look at his answer list, it is basically the same as [this user's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2247002/rick-barry) question list (the same user who posted the trolling answer). It seems they just ask and answer each other's questions.
3. The second user asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15843916/1204143), and the first user's [complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15843928/1204143) came in **46 seconds later**. I've only ever known Jon Skeet to answer that fast.

Basically, I have to suspect that the same guy operates both accounts linked here, and is just switching between the two to answer questions and game rep. He also seems to have taken a shining to randomly downvoting other answers.

Comment: We're actually talking about this in chat right now.

Comment: @Mysticial: Which chat?

Comment: Moderators are aware of those accounts; we're looking into them now.

Comment: Lounge<C++>. I first noticed the obscenely fast answer to [this first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843528/what-is-type-casting-in-c). This was about an hour ago.

Comment: @Andrew "Cool down"? Shouldn't it be "Voting irregularities" or "Breaking the rules"?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd There are multiple things going on with them.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Please refrain from asking details on suspensions. There's only so much a moderator is allowed to share, and asking for more details puts as in a very awkward position.

Comment: @Yannis sure, didn't occur to me there's more than sockpuppet accounts used to farm rep. Now with Brad's answer and the link to the troll answer it's all clear.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had already suspended the one for the highly abusive answer when I came across the other. I've given both a little time away from the site while we unravel this.

I've also deleted a couple other accounts that appear to be from these same user(s).

The odd thing here was [this trolling answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841846/do-this-thing-i-dont-get-it/15841879#15841879) and its comments racked up a bunch of offensive flags, but moderators never saw those. They were apparently cleared when the user deleted their own post. That seems like a bug to me. Might be time for a feature request.

Comment: While I can't see any of their deleted answers or questions, it certainly sounds like they've been busy...

Comment: @nneonneo [deleted answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eI4fb.png) and [the question it answered](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cvVOP.png) :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd He has 10k. So he can see it. Just not on the user profiles.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. I wasn't clear. (But, the question and answer is rather amusing, if only because of the rather crappy attempt at trolling)

Comment: @Mysticial oh my, didn't check! Well, it's still useful for the poor <10K'ers who happen to wander here somehow. :)

Comment: So, the suspensions end tomorrow...any luck unravelling the story here?

Comment: @nneonneo - I don't know that there was a story beyond someone trolling the site. They haven't come back since being suspended, so they might have had their fun and are now on their way.