# Any pending spam flags on answers are dismissed if the question is (self-)deleted

Tags: bug, flags, self-delete

This question is related to a post that showed up on [meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380244/6296561) today: it seems like (self-)deletion of the question dismisses pending spam flags on answers.

This appears to be a bug, since [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273402/332043) (although on invalidation) says the flags should be *preserved* and not dismissed.

Comment: It wasn't validated because of a self-deletion. It was validated because it was deleted along with the question being deleted.

Comment: Oh. But is it still triggered by self-deletion?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. Unless there's evidence somewhere that it isn't working.